# Flask (python) in pycharm fails: "required field missing"

Tags: windows-10, python, pycharm

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = Flask(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\ANAS\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 559, in __init__
    self.add_url_rule(
  File "C:\Users\ANAS\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 67, in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ANAS\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1217, in add_url_rule
    self.url_map.add(rule)
  File "C:\Users\ANAS\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 1388, in add
    rule.bind(self)
  File "C:\Users\ANAS\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 730, in bind
    self.compile()
  File "C:\Users\ANAS\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 794, in compile
    self._build = self._compile_builder(False).__get__(self, None)
  File "C:\Users\ANAS\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\routing.py", line 951, in _compile_builder
    code = compile(module, "<werkzeug routing>", "exec")
TypeError: required field "type_ignores" missing from Module
```

Comment: "please help me," No, your question is off topic and would also be closed on [so] as it doesn't meet their requirements for a good question. As a minimum it should include your source code.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The issue is with a backwards-incompatible change in Python 3.8. See   https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1551.